# Position image center of div whetever image size

Tags: html, css, image, alignment, css-position

I have in a problem with centering an image.Hence I have many div and in every div have two div that is divided into two.In those two div I will show two image.Each of these two div is 300 pixel.Problem is images may be small or 300 pixel and I have to show images center if small and if image is 300 then automatically sit on full div. Can anyone help me to do this?

Here is the code..

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;height: 300px;width: 600px;background: whitesmoke">
    <div style="float:left;width: 300px;height: 300px;">
        <img class="" src="images/productImages/medium/<?php echo $product1['product_image']?>" alt="image_01" width="" height="" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;width: 300px;height: 300px;">
        <?php if(!empty($product2)) { ?>
        <img class="" src="images/productImages/medium/<?php echo $product2['product_image']?>" alt="image_02" width="" height="" />
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: showing code is helpfull...html and css please...??

Comment: what have you done so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you have to position the parent with "relative" and than you can handle the IMGs with position "absolute" ;)

[take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/fk8Mf/)

```
.CenterMe {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: table-cell;` for the parent element and than use `max-height` and `max-width` properties for your `img` tag.. This way you can align the images vertically as well as horizontally.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9VGB/)

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

---

But if you are looking to align images only horizontally and not vertically, than you won't need to do much, just declare `text-align: center;` on the parent element.

Comment: @RaselAhmed you welcome :) if this helps you, than consider marking my answer as correct so that it helps future visitors to refer.. click on the tick besides my answer..

Comment: Mr.Alien your solution worked nice but in internet explorer 7 it is not working.all images are showing vertically one by one. Please can you give me the solution for internet explorer so that images can be centered position horizontally by two.?

Answer (score 0):

Use image as background and set position to center:

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;height: 300px;width: 600px;background: whitesmoke">
    <div style="float:left; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-image: url('images/productImages/medium/<?php echo $product2['product_image']?>'; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `text-align:center` to your image container:

```
<div style="float:left;width: 300px;height: 300px; text-align:center">
        <img class="" src="images/productImages/medium/<?php echo $product1['product_image']?>" alt="image_01" width="" height="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, considering your images and condition are both dynamic, modify your inline css to :

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;height: 300px;width: 600px;background: whitesmoke;text-align:center">
```

added : `text-align:center`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/jzdm2/)